# How to use multiple threads (each is an email account) to send Emails from Queue via SMTP sequentially

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, exchange-server

The problem started here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-GB/office365/servicedescriptions/exchange-online-service-description/exchange-online-limits#receiving-and-sending-limits

Office365 allows an email account to send 10,000 emails within 24 hours and the rate limit is 30 emails per 60 seconds.

My idea is to

- create a Queue to hold the emails.
- single thread that access the DB, fetch emails, and append to the Queue.
- 10 threads, each will access the Queue (each 3s), and send an email using its own email account.

Now I can guarantee that each email account (thread) will send maximum 20 emails per 60 seconds.

If the Queue is full (eg. 10000 emails), all email accounts (threads) will work similarly and as expected as they find emails when they try to access the Queue, while if the Queue is empty, there will be different in the processed emails count for each thread. How can I pause all threads when the Queue is empty to make sure that all email accounts (threads) will be used similarly.

Or if there are better ways to achieve this ?

```
   using Message = KeyValuePair<long, Email>;
   static ConcurrentQueue<Message> emails_queue = new ConcurrentQueue<Message>();
   static Thread GetDBEmailsThread;
```

```
static void SendEmails1()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if (emails_queue.Count == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + " " + Thread.CurrentThread.Name + " - " + "Sleeping for 5s");
                    Thread.Sleep(5000);
                    continue;
                }
                try
                {
                    Message msg;
                    // process messages
                    // we use Try here because we're multithreaded
                    // so it's possible that between the Wait() call
                    // and the dequeue call the queue may be cleared
                    if (emails_queue.TryDequeue(out msg))
                    {
                        Email email = msg.Value;
                        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + " " + Thread.CurrentThread.Name + " - " + "is handling : " + msg.Key + " - " + email.Subject);
                        // Done, move email to sent items
                        SendEmail(email, Constants.SS_EMAIL_1);
                        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + " " + Thread.CurrentThread.Name + " - " + "email " + msg.Key + " - " + "sent.");
                    }
                }                
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + " " + Thread.CurrentThread.Name + " - " + " " + "Exception. \r\n" + e.Message);
                }
                finally
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(3000);
                    emails_queue_available.Release();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Use a BlockingCollection to wrap your queue

Comment: nice suggestion, but if I use Thread1->BlockingCollection.Take() , this will block the current thread only, lets see after two seconds (and before Thread1 tries again) Thread2->BlockingCollection.Take() and there were items to take, this means that Thread2 was able to take before Thread1.